# Following file history from a fork in git

Tags: git

I know at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869b93fe74f4d6cb2dd6f6c3e9bf9daee39ba19 Webkit was merged into chromium/blink. So I want to trace how the files evolved or were moved around over time.

However I click a random file's Log, all I see is the **initial commit**:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/d869b93fe74f4d6cb2dd6f6c3e9bf9daee39ba19/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/khtml/README.tags

That file doesn't exist in the source checkout!

```
~/sloc/blink $ git config --get remote.origin.url
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src
~/sloc/blink $ find -name README.tags
~/sloc/blink $ git log -- third_party/WebKit/WebCore/khtml/README.tags
~/sloc/blink $
```

Though `git show d869b93fe74f4d6cb2dd6f6c3e9bf9daee39ba19` is there. So what am I missing to follow this file?

Comment: What is your current active branch/commit ?

Answer (score 0):

I cloned the repo, and I don't see the commit `d869b93fe74f4d6cb2dd6f6c3e9bf9daee39ba19` you mention. This means it is not part of the history of the `trunk` branch.

Look at what other refs you have locally, you may try `git log --oneline --graph --all --simplify-by-decoration` to have an overview of what refs you have at hand.